# Why is javascript saying that addcallback function is not defined?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, html, swfobject

my first time on here.

My problem is with AS3, Javascript and possibly the browsers Firefox and IE.

I have done so much searching for an answer so i will print my code:

i am using this line to call the flash application and in all browsers its combatible and actually traces in firebug to hold an OBJECT->FLASH_ID so thats not the problem.

```
var obj = document.getElementById('test');
```

then i use addcallback:

```
obj.sendStatus(loggedIn);
```

now whats weird is that i trace all individual elments in chrome and

1. -obj = flash object
2. -sendStatus = flash->function
3. -loggedIn = either false or true;

everything works great but when i am on firefox or ie
it traces differently

1. -obj = flash object
2. -sendStatus = undefined
3. -loggedIn = either true or false;

now what am i missing??????????

1. i tried embedding rather than object insertion
2. i made sure that the id's were all unique
3. i checked to make sure i had the right flash object selected with getElementById

im so confused.. and it feels like something simple.

Answer (score 0):

I know about some browser - dependent timing problems, making the interface of the flash object available...

A timer could help, try this:

```
var obj = document.getElementById('test');
setTimeout(function(){obj.sendStatus(loggedIn);}, 500);
```

500 is a bit to long, but just to be sure. If it works you can try to lower it to 200 - 300.

Comment: okay i tried it, and its not working; its gets me thinking though - ExternalInterface.available just checks whether the container it is inside of is a html document, so i know to use $(document).ready() and $(window).load(.. but can flash access the DOM before it is ready?

Comment: uhm.. I don't understand you quite well. But another thing, is it maybe a logging issue, are you sure the method is not being called?

Comment: yeh the method, i assume you mean the callback; it is being called in Firefox and Chrome, but not IE - what do you mean by logging?? What i mean is could the there be calls made from flash player to javascript before the DOM is ready? are flash elements loaded before javascript is?

Comment: you just have to make sure that you are accessing the flash object, which is a DOM element, when the document is ready. And there also seem to be timing issues with this object making it's javascript interface available, that's why I suggested the timer. But you tested that and it doesn't work. In your original post you say it doesn't work in firefox and ie, here you say it doesn't work only in ie - which is true? My question was only, are you sure the callback is not executed in flash? have you debugged it, have you put traces in the method?

Comment: hey lxx callback is not executed, as the element is undefined and flash bug confirms that also. The way i just got it to work in Firefox is that i removed object within object and just used imbed instead and it decided to work in firefox but not IE. so IE is the only browser that is saying that its an undefined element

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure you declared allowScriptAccess = sameDomain both in embed tag and object tag
   in case you don't use swfObject
2. Maybe the way you get a reference to the swf is wrong, try this

   ```
   function thisMovie(movieName) {
        if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
            return window[movieName];
        } else {
            return document[movieName];
        }
    }
   ```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that using `ExternalInterface` requires both parties (`browser` and `flash`) to be ready.

You can have the flash poll a method in the page which just returns true so that you know its ready to receive calls from flash.

On the flip side if the page is cached, it can sometimes happen that the page wants to send to flash before flash is ready, so I use a callback to the page telling it flash is ready, so its like a handshake, once both parties are ready, then we can start sending data back and forth.

This has been my approach since Firefox 3.